# It's not possible to produce and subscribe to events using Otto?

Tags: android, android-fragments, otto

I'm trying to Subscribe and Post from the same fragment, but I'm getting this error when i try to register the fragment:

```
...(my method) has @Produce annotation but requires 1 arguments.  Methods must require zero arguments.
```

on

```
 BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
```

So i guess it's not possible, but maybe there is an alternative without additional interfaces.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods annotated with `@Produce` must not take any arguments. They should just return the event object.

"I'm trying to Subscribe and Post" suggests you probably need to change it to `@Subscribe` annotation instead.

For posting events, just use `post()`. `@Produce` is meant for returning the latest value of an event.

Comment: I need to post 1 object and receive 1 object from another place. I need both operations for different objects.

Comment: Use `post()` for posting then.

Comment: oh thanks!. I thought that it was necessary to write the @Produce + method thing all the time.